# SQL Server 2005 row to columns GPS data mapping in scatter graph

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have GPS data that I need to change from columns to rows but keep the `shiftindex`, `ID` listed for each new row that will be made for each GPS "x**","y**" my goal is to put these GPS locations into a SSRS scatter graph with a amp background and map out the units travels for a set shiftindex. below is how the data looks now and what Im trying to get it to look like to make it useable. there are 15 GPS locations for each time stamp, there can also be mutable Id + Time per shift index.

How data is stored

```
Shiftindex   ID       Time    x00        x01     x02        x03
31805        RD2015   438      9986.76    9989.461   10027.5    10058.58
31805        RD1288   444     10643.28   10643.28    10645.98   10667.59
```

How I would like data to look for scatter graph

```
Shiftindex      ID             Time  xGPS       yGPS        
31805           RD2015          438  9986.76    29463.66        
31805           RD2015          438  9989.461   29463.14        
31805           RD2015          438  10027.5    29471.44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Shiftindex, ID, Time, x00 AS xGPS, y00 AS yGPS
FROM GPS

UNION

SELECT Shiftindex, ID, Time, x01 AS xGPS, y00 AS yGPS
FROM GPS
```

Etc

Comment: Thanks for that never thought to use union in that way but it got the neede results Thanks again